# no function is mapped to the name "action:output" , oozie shell action

Tags: oozie

According to [oozie documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.5_Ssh_Action), you can capture output of a shell action using the function `String action:output(String node, String key)` but when I use it in my decision node like
`<decision name="mydecision">
        <switch>
            <case to="shell1">
              ${action:output('decideScript','decide.next.step.name') = 'shell1'}
            </case>
            <default to="end"/>
        </switch>
    </decision>`

Oozie throws me an error saying `no function is mapped to the name "action:output" , oozie shell action`

Answer (score 2):

The seems to be an error in oozie documentation of shell action. Use `{wf:actionData('decideScript')['decide.next.step.name'] = 'shell1}` as your EL instead.

Comment: Can you please explain what's `decideScript` and `decide.next.step.name` and `shell1` ?

Comment: 'decideScript' would be the name of the node/action that is outputting the data (not shown in the code above). 'decide.next.step.name' is the name of the property output by the decideScript node and 'shell1' is what it's being compared to. Though I think the above should be == or eq rather than =. [Here's](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-use-oozie-shell-and-java-actions/) a guide.

Comment: This worked like magic. The oozie documentation is misleading. Thank you for this answer.